# Which APIs or modules do I need for controlling mouse and pasting?

Tags: python, winapi, mouse, mouseevent

I am trying to write a program that can enter text into text input on the internet (e.g. forms).

I am using win32api to control the mouse. What I have been doing is using Tkinter to put the text I am inputting on the clipboard and then using win32api to 'click' the mouse into the text input area. I then get the program to right click and select 'paste.' Unfortunately this last step does not work, and often jams the program.

So my question really boils down to 'is there an easier way to do this (there must be) and what APIs or modules will I need?'

Here is some of my code:

```
import clicker
from Tkinter import Tk

COORDS_TEXT_X = 440
COORDS_TEXT_Y = 225

r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('hello')
r.destroy()

clicker.Rclick(COORDS_TEXT_X, COORDS_TEXT_Y)
clicker.click(COORDS_TEXT_X + 50, COORDS_TEXT_Y + 88)
```

And here is clicker:

```
import win32api, win32con

def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)

def Rclick(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, x, y, 0, 0)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using this "macro" on a external app or the webbrowser is inside yours?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm not that experienced in programming.